# "git grep <pattern>" for just python (or any type of) files?

Tags: git, git-grep

When I'm trying to find a pattern in a git-based project, I type:

```
git grep <pattern>
```

and git searches the entire project for that pattern. Sometimes this finds matches in non-source files, which makes finding what I'm looking for harder.

How can I tell it to only search Python (.py) or some other source files?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep

Comment: The `--` is optional, but I advise using it: `git grep ... -- '*.py'`.  The quotes around `*.py` are required if you're using a typical shell *and* there are `*.py` files in the current directory *and* you want Git to search all subdirectories too.

Comment: Just for completeness: `git grep <pattern> -- \*.py`; the backslash screens shell metacharacter (asterisk) in a way similar to apostrophes: `'*.py'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

### Sytntax

```
git grep <pattern> -- '*.<ext>'
```

Where :

- `pattern` is the pattern to look for
- `ext` is the extension,in our case it is to look in all the files that contain `<ext>`

### Example

```
git grep HelloWorld -- '*.json'
```

Comment: May you have 100 sons.